# Calling generator function from setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-generator

The following js code fails in developer console of firefox, chrome and nodejs as well. Unable to figure out why?

```js
function* x() {}
let y = x()
setTimeout(y.next, 100)
```

Error in firefox

> TypeError: CallGeneratorMethodIfWrapped method called on incompatible
>   Window

Error in chrome

> Uncaught TypeError: Method [Generator].prototype.next called on
>   incompatible receiver #
>       at next ()

Error in node.js

```
timers.js:475
    timer._onTimeout();
          ^

TypeError: Method [Generator].prototype.next called on incompatible receiver #<Timeout>
    at Timeout.next [as _onTimeout] (<anonymous>)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)
```

Comment: how about `setTimeout(function(){ y.next(); }, 100)` ?

Comment: Relevant read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `y` is lost when you pass `y.next` as the function to be called.  You can do this:

```
setTimeout(y.next.bind(y), 100)
```

When you pass `y.next`, it reaches onto the `y` object and gets a reference to the `next` function and it passes just a reference to the `next` function.  It's a generic reference to the `next` function that has no association at all with the `y` object.  Then, later when the `setTimeout()` fires, it just calls the `next` function all by itself and the object `y` is not used in the function call.  That means that when `next` executes, the `this` value will be `undefined` and will not be the appropriate `y` object.

You can imagine it doing this:

```
let x = y.next;
setTimeout(x, 100);
```

Nothing to do with `y` was passed to `setTimeout()`.  It's going to call that `next()` method as a normal function.  You could see the same problem if you did this:

```
let x = y.next;
x();
```

By its design, `setTimeout()` just calls functions as in `fn()`.  It doesn't call methods as in `y.next()`.  To call a method, the object reference has to be used in the actual function call as you see in `y.next()`.  `setTimeout()` does not do that.  It just calls functions.

So, `.bind()` creates a small little stub function that will then call it properly for you.  So, using it as I showed above is analogous to this:

```
let x = function() {
    y.next();
}
setTimeout(x, 100);
```

Or, the inline version:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    y.next();
}, 100);
```

Comment: Or pass a lambda: `setTimeout(() => y.next(), 100)`. @VLAZ: definitely, I'm slightly biased to use lambdas more than to anonymous functions, but thats a valid option

Comment: @Caramiriel even a normal function would work `function() { y.next() }` - in either case the invocation will have the context set correctly.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain why the context of y is necessary? y.next is already a function, so why invocation of y.next fails.

Comment: "*y.next is already a function*" correction it's a **method** and that is precisely why it matters. A quick explanation of terminology would help - a *function* is an unbound procedure that (generally) takes some input and produces an output. A *method* is nearly the same when looked from afar - it still takes input and produces an output but it's bound to an *object*. So, in short if you are calling `someObj.something()` it's a method, if you are calling `something()` it's a function. A method may depend on its context - the object. Thus disassociating the context can break a method.

Comment: @chinoy probably the most important difference is that *methods* would be using `this` to access the object they belong to. Which is why `this` is called the context - it's the part of the procedure that's *outside* the procedure's current scope but the code uses stuff. E.g. calling `this.someVariable++`. No context and the code breaks or behaves unexpectedly. A method might not use the context, in which case it's safe to divorce it but it's not easy to say if it does or not.

Comment: the more correct use would be [`Generator.prototype.next`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next) and this requires a binding of `this`.

Comment: thanks @VLAZ. Makes sense as  with yield*, the generator function delegates to another generator function.

Comment: @chinoy - I added more explanation to my answer.  The boss came a callin' so I was away for a bit.